# How to build a JSON object in Postgres without explicitly referencing every single column

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following query (Postgres 10.x):

```sql
select json_agg(
  json_build_object('id', m.id, 'name', m.name, 'folder_id', m.folder_id, 'created_at', m.created_at, 'updated_at', m.updated_at, 'item_type', m.item_type, 'deleted', m.deleted, 'deleted_at', m.deleted_at, 'virtual', m.virtual, 'duration', m.duration, 'filesize', m.filesize, 'original_filename', m.original_filename, 'snippet_detail', row_to_json(s.*))
)
from media m
join snippets as s on s.media_id = m.id
where item_type = 'SNIPPET' and source_media_id = '5e4ef00e-c6b7-4c24-8b4e-820acc5823d9';
```

It's obviously very tedious to have to list every single column in `json_build_object`. Is there some shorthand way to build a JSON object from `m.*`, while still keeping the last `row_to_json` result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select row_to_json(x.*) from (
    select m.*, row_to_json(s.*) as snippet_detail
    from media m join snippets s on s.media_id = m.id
    where item_type = 'SNIPPET' and source_media_id = '5e4ef00e-c6b7-4c24-8b4e-820acc5823d9'
) x;
```